# Populate Collection from Struts2 Form Submission

Tags: java, struts2, struts

I'm trying to populate a List of beans from a form:

```
public class Foo {
   public String attr1;
   public String attr2;
}

public class Bar {
   public List<Foo> foos;
}

public class StrutsAction extends Action {
   public Bar bar;
}
```

So in my Struts2 form, what's the best way to populate Foo?  Intuitively, I want to do:

```
<input type="hidden" name="bar.foos.attr1" />
```

but that isn't working and would cause collisions.  I'm sure the answer is very simple and I'm overlooking it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you just want different name for each hidden field?

```
<s:iterator value="bars" status="key">
    <s:hidden name="bar.foos[%{#key.index}].attr1" value="attr1" />
    <s:hidden name="bar.foos[%{#key.index}].attr2" value="attr2" />
</s:iterator>
```

which should give you the equivalent of

```
<input type="hidden" name="bar.foos[0].attr1" value="some value" />
<input type="hidden" name="bar.foos[0].attr2" value="some other value" />
<input type="hidden" name="bar.foos[1].attr1" value="some value" />
<input type="hidden" name="bar.foos[1].attr2" value="some other value" />
```

If you have proper getter/setter, it should set all the values when the form is being submitted.

Comment: You are correct sir.  I suppose I simply didn't know the proper syntax (i.e. the [0]).

Comment: Thank you...! it helped me too...(even after 2 years :-P)