# Populate List<String> in struts2 from form data

Tags: java, list, struts2, struts

I feel this should be exceedingly obvious, but so far I've failed to find an answer.

I want to have a list of strings (or an array of strings, I really don't care) get populated by form data in Struts2.

I've seen several examples of how to do [indexed properties with beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975883/populate-collection-from-struts2-form-submission), but wrapping a single string inside an object seems fairly silly.

So I have something like

```
    public class Controller extends ActionSupport {

        private List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        public Controller() {
            strings.add("1");
            strings.add("2");
            strings.add("3");
            strings.add("4");
            strings.add("5");
        }
        public String execute() throws Exception {
            return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
        }
        public List<String> getStrings() {
            return strings;
        }

        public void setStrings(List<String> s) {
            strings = s;
        }
    }
```

...

```
<s:iterator value="strings" status="stringStatus">
   <s:textfield name="strings[%{#stringStatus.index}]" style="width: 5em" />
</s:iterator>
```

The form fields get populated with their initial values (e.g. 1, 2, etc), but the results are not properly posted back. `setStrings` is never called, but the values get set to empty strings.

Anybody have any idea what's going on? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe as you have it, your jsp code would render something like:

```
<input type="text" name="strings[0]" style="width: 5em" value="1"/>
<input type="text" name="strings[1]" style="width: 5em" value="2"/>
<input type="text" name="strings[2]" style="width: 5em" value="3"/>
...
```

Notice that the name of the field references are "strings[x]" where as you need the name to be just "strings".  I would suggest something like:

```
<s:iterator value="strings" status="stringStatus">
   <s:textfield name="strings" value="%{[0].toString()}" style="width: 5em" />
</s:iterator>
```

Not sure if the value attribute above may is correct, but I think something like this will get you the desired result.

Comment: That works, thanks! It seems odd that you have to specify the value for what seems to be the simple case, but not for beans. *shrug*

Also, when you say that 'the name of the field references are "strings[x]" where as you need the name to be just "string,"' I'm assuming you mean "strings"...?

Finally, the former would be the correct format for beans, right (e.g. people[0].name with ArrayList<Person> people)?

Comment: Please mark this answer as solved if it has solved the issue.

Comment: @Quaternion: Already done. Though he (seemingly inadvertently) edited out the key part of his solution; that is, the value should be along the lines of %{getStrings().get(#stringStatus.index)}

Comment: @Chris:I'm not sure the value field has to be that complex.  Did you try it with just the value="[0]"?  I forgot when I initially posted the answer that it's in an iterator loops which may remove the need for the complex %{getStrings().get(#stringStatus.index)}

Comment: Yes the expression should be reducible to at least value="%{[#stringStatus.index]}", and you should be able to drop the %{} because the should assume OGNL in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately that (and a large number of 'simpler' things I tried with and without braces) didn't work.

Comment: You are right, the reason is that the iterator is pushing the string onto the stack, so you'll see inside the iterator <s:property/> will render the string, I should have really tested first! I will test something, that should make this much shorter.

Comment: Well just for educational value... this also works, but it isn't as short as I'd like: <s:iterator value="strings" status="stat"><s:textfield name="[%{#stat.index}]" value="%{#this.toString()}"/></s:iterator>

Comment: @Quaternion: Thanks for that idea.  I corrected the answer above and it should now work and is slightly simpler than what I had originally posted and hopefully makes more sense.

Comment: @nmc: I assume you meant value="%{#this.toString()} ?